# DownloadManager in android TV

Tags: android, android-studio, android-download-manager, android-tv

I'm new to android development, I'm trying to implement this on an android tv emulator without success, is it any special consideration for this scenario? If I run on tablet or phone emulator it works fine, I've followed the guidelines to run on android TV, even creating a new specific project for TV but no success.

My application is only about downloading a list of videos depending on the date and when download finishes the video will be shown on a VideoView.

Hope you could help me.﻿

Comment: What errors do you receive?

Comment: The log shows no error, well ithink, the only thing that shows is this.

Comment: 08-18 11:59:12.836 2413-2549/com.example.cristianjoseortizramirez.pantallasinformativas W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb42e6460, error=EGL_SUCCESS

Comment: The application only starts only and no download begins, as I said this only happens on tv emulator

Comment: Did you try to debug it?

Comment: Yes, I already debug but no error or exception is trhown, I tested puting directly on the VideoView and it works fine on TV emulator, so the problem relies on the DownloadManager I think.

Comment: Finally It's working I was missing some confutation properties, now I want to add a progress bar or something that shows the downloading process.

Comment: How can I achieve that? hope your herlp